# Remap keys per keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Background: I typically wish to remap keys on my laptop keyboard, but not on external USB keyboards I connect to the laptop. I'm aware of a solution for [linux](https://superuser.com/q/760602/1245021), as well as several options how to remap keys on windows for all keyboards (e.g. [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys)).

Question: Is there any way to remap keyboard keys for a single keyboard only on Windows 10?

Comment: Not possible on Windows

Comment: Have you tried the Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center? In the step 2 it mentioned: Connect the keyboard that you want to configure.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-do-i-reassign-hot-keys-for-my-keyboard-703f897c-ad72-db5d-8e64-0928873d712f

Comment: @Jenny - looks like that tool is only for Microsoft devices.

Comment: Hm, it seems like it might be possible, at least theoretically looking at this: https://github.com/cajhin/capsicain/issues/44

Comment: @DavidPostill:  It is possible, just not particularly easy.  Please see my answer for two possible approaches to solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at: https://github.com/evilC/AutoHotInterception

Based on: https://github.com/oblitum/Interception

Not sure whether it's supported on Windows 11 yet:

https://github.com/oblitum/Interception/issues/133

However, note that the Interception keyboard *driver* is closed source, which may present a problem for some users, but is nevertheless digitally signed.

A "driverless" option can be hacked together by combining Raw Input and Keyboard Hook messages to selectively block input from multiple keyboards, but this approach is not without its own set of challenges:

[Combining Windows Raw Input and Keyboard Hook to Disambiguate Multiple Keyboard Devices](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/716591/combining-raw-input-and-keyboard-hook-to-selective)